# Is there a better or faster solution to round up or down from half in python without any libraries?

Tags: python, rounding

In python the function round() just rounds half to the nearest even number. That's my version of the code to round always down or up from half. I'm sure there's a better way to do so, what's your advice? Thank you.

```
def rounding(number, levels = 0, up = False):
    n = number * (10 ** levels)
    nint = int(n)
    up = 1 if (up is True and number > 0) or (up is False and number < 0) else 0
    return (nint + round(n - nint + up) - up) / (10 ** levels)
```

if up is True than round up from half, if False round down from half (for up I mean towards infinity, also for negative numbers).

Levels rappresent the decimal place to round

test the code 1:

```
for i in range(-13, 15, 2):
    n = i / 2
    print(n, '=>', rounding(n))
```

test the code 2:

```
for i in range(-13, 15, 2):
    n = i / 2
    print(n, '=>', rounding(n, up = True))
```

test the code 3:

```
for i in range(-13, 15, 2):
    n = i / 2 + 0.005
    print(n, '=>', rounding(n, 2, True))
```

due to accuracy errors of float numbers, this code doesn't work with too many levels, but I've same errors with round(). To fix this problem I found this solution:

```
def rounding(number, levels = 0, up = False):
    n = round(number * (10 ** levels), len(str(number).split('.')[1]) - levels)
    nint = int(n)
    up = 1 if (up is True and number > 0) or (up is False and number < 0) else 0
    return (nint + round(n - nint + up) - up) / (10 ** levels)
```

test the code:

```
for i in range(-21, 22, 2):
    n = i / 2 + 0.00000000000005
    print(n, '=>', rounding(n, 13, True))
```

Comment: If `up` is `True`, return `round(...)`; else, return `floor(...)` - something like that? If not, maybe explain what your code really does? Explaining in normal language might help you translate the code into a simple form.

Comment: The betterness of the way depends on the person. What to count as a library and what as a core functionality is speculative. Python has integer division operator, `x//1` rounds down, `(x+.5)//1` rounds up. I bet it is faster.

Comment: if up is True than round up from half, if False round down from half. Levels rappresent the decimal place to round, for example: 0.5 is 1 if up is True, otherwise 0, sorry, i forgot to explain it

Comment: "up" and "down" are a bit ambiguous as directions for negative numbers. For "up", do you mean "towards infinity" or "away from zero"? Similar question for "down": do you mean "towards zero" or "towards negative infinity"?

Comment: for up I mean towards infinity, also for negative numbers